# How can I run .sql file having multiple .sql file inside using Snowsql?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I want to figure out how to run multiple sql files on one go. Suppose I have this test.sql file which has file1.sql, file2.sql and file3.sql and so on. Along with some DML/DDL.

```
use database &{db};
use schema &{sc};

file1.sql;
file2.sql;
file3.sql;

create table snow_test1
(
name varchar
,add1 varchar
,id number
)
comment = 'this is snowsql testing table' ;

desc table snow_test1;

insert into snow_test1 
values('prachi', 'testing', 1);

select * from snow_test1;
```

here what I run in power shell,

```
snowsql -c pp_conn -f ...\test.sql -D  db=tbc -D  sc=testing;
```

Is there any way to do this ? I know It is possible in Oracle but I want to do this using snowsql. Please  guide me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run multiple files in a single call:

```
snowsql -c pp_conn -f file1.sql -f file2.sql -f file3.sql -D  db=tbc -D  sc=testing;
```

You might need to put the addition DMLs in a file.

Comment: That is possible but I want to run like this. So, I can put as many files as I want and run just one .sql file.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried using !source. But the problem is with multiple .sql files. I dont know how to define multiple .sql files inside my test.sql file. Do I need to call something like this in my file: !source  file1.sql; !source file2.sql; !source file3.sql; Let me know if this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried defining .sql file with !source inside my test.sql file and its working:

```
!source file1.sql;
!source file2.sql;
!source file3.sql;

....
```

Also, run the same command in power shell using one .sql file and it is working.